# How to solve this ERROR while cloning code from gcp?

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform

Here is my error while cloning code in the repository. can anyone tell me how to solve this

```
lasyas-Air:cloud push lasyavaliveti$ gcloud source repos clone Android --project=samyata-191502
Cloning into '/Users/lasyavaliveti/Desktop/cloud push/Android'...
remote: Sending approximately 155.22 MiB ...
remote: Total 27123 (delta 12826), reused 27123 (delta 12826)
error: inflate: data stream error (invalid distance too far back)
fatal: pack has bad object at offset 162523573: inflate returned -3
fatal: index-pack failed
ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.clone) Command '[u'git', u'clone', u'https://source.developers.google.com/p/samyata-191502/r/Android', u'/Users/lasyavaliveti/Desktop/cloud push/Android', u'--config', u'credential.helper=', u'--config', u'credential.helper=!gcloud auth git-helper --account=lasya.valiveti@yamyah.com --ignore-unknown $@']' returned non-zero exit status 128
lasyas-Air:cloud push lasyavaliveti$
```

Some things to try next:

- Run `gcloud --help` to see the Cloud Platform services you can interact with. And run `gcloud help COMMAND` to get help on any gcloud command.
- Run `gcloud topic -h` to learn about advanced features of the SDK like arg files and output formatting

Thanks in advance, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. First download the official Google Cloud SDK archive file from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-macos.
2. Unzip the archive and save it at your desired folder.
3. Now open the folder which contains your unzipped google-cloud-sdk folder in terminal.
4. Run the command sh ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh and give yes to all further prompts and you are done.